# Vue Multiselect is not submitting ID value (Rails API)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, select, vue.js, vue-multiselect

My app is a Rails API backend and VueJS via Nuxt front end.

I have a form where one of the inputs is a select and I'm using [vue-multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org). The select options are values from a different table, where I want to display the name field, but submit the ID.

I am able to display the options in the drop drown ok, and I'm also submitting other values in the form, but the ID is not working.

Rails console shows the error of `distillery_id` not being a permitted parameter, although I do have this set in the controller.

```
Started POST "/api/v1/gins" for ::1 at 2019-02-01 13:25:38 +0000
Processing by Api::V1::GinsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"gin_name"=>"distillery_id", "description"=>"distillery_id should be submitted", "distillery_id"=>{"id"=>3, "distillery_name"=>"Gordon's", "snippet"=>nil, "description"=>nil, "website"=>nil, "country"=>"United Kingdom", "created_at"=>"2019-01-29T13:46:15.088Z", "updated_at"=>"2019-01-29T13:46:15.088Z", "slug"=>nil}, "abv"=>"0", "snippet"=>"distillery_id now?", "gin"=>{"gin_name"=>"distillery_id", "snippet"=>"distillery_id now?", "description"=>"distillery_id should be submitted", "abv"=>"0", "distillery_id"=>{"id"=>3, "distillery_name"=>"Gordon's", "snippet"=>nil, "description"=>nil, "website"=>nil, "country"=>"United Kingdom", "created_at"=>"2019-01-29T13:46:15.088Z", "updated_at"=>"2019-01-29T13:46:15.088Z", "slug"=>nil}}}
Unpermitted parameter: :distillery_id
```

**gins_controller.rb**

```
...
    def gin_params
      params.require(:gin).permit(:gin_name, :alcoholic, :snippet, :description, :abv, :distillery_id)
    end
...
```

**new.vue**

```
<template>
  <section class="container">
    <div>
      <h1>Gins</h1>
      <form @submit.stop.prevent="addGin">
        <h2>New Gin</h2>
        <p>
            <label for="gin_name" class="input-label">Title:</label>
            <input id="gin_name" v-model="gin_name" type="gin_name" name="gin_name" class="input">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="snippet" class="input-label">Snippet:</label>
            <input id="snippet" v-model="snippet" type="text" name="snippet" class="input">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="description" class="input-label">Description:</label>
            <input id="description" v-model="description" type="textarea" name="description" class="input">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="abv" class="input-label">ABV%:</label>
            <input id="abv" v-model="abv" type="number" name="abv" class="input">
        </p>
          <div>
            <label for="distillery_id" class="input-label">Distillery:</label>
            <multiselect
                v-model="distillery_id"
                track_by="distillery_id"
                :options="options"
                :searchable="true"
                placeholder="Choose One Distillery"
                :custom-label="label"
                >
            </multiselect>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'

export default {

  components: { Multiselect },
  data() {
    return {
      gin_name: '',
      snippet: '',
      description: '',
      abv: '',
      distillery_id: '',
      options: []
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getDistilleries()
  },

  methods: {

    label(option) {
      return `${option.distillery_name}`
    },

    addGin() {
      axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/gins', {
        gin_name: this.gin_name, description: this.description, distillery_id: this.distillery_id, abv: this.abv, snippet: this.snippet
      })
        .then((response) => {})
      console.log()
    },
    getDistilleries(req) {
      axios.get('/api/v1/distilleries')
        .then((res) => {
          this.options = res.data
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }

  }
}
</script>
<style src="vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css"></style>
<style>

</style>
```

Based on the console, I suspect this is a rails issue rather than vue, but that permitted params looks good to me.

Any suggestions what else could be amiss?

Comment: you're sending an `{}` in `distillery_id` and permitting as single value instead, accept as `{}` and try it.

Comment: do you mean in the `gins_controller`? Like this `distillery_id:[]`

Comment: `distillery_id:{}` like this

Comment: ok, we're getting somewhere. The console no longer complains about permitted parameter, BUT it's still no submitting the field.

`Gin Create (32.5ms)  INSERT INTO "gins" ("gin_name", "snippet", "description", "abv", "created_at", "updated_at", "slug", "alcoholic") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"`

Comment: Not submitting distillery_id?

Comment: Correct. Not submitting distillery_id

Comment: Thanks. Sure . I've had to step out for a bit. Will be back on soon.

Comment: Am I correct in that your distillery select only allows for one option selected?

Comment: @RobNice yes, that's correct.

Comment: What does your getDistilleries component method return? An array of IDs or objects?

Answer (score 1):

Caution, this is untested. But, after having a quick look at VueMultiselect's docs and your Vue component, it looks like your distillery_id v-model is being set to a single distillery object. Which I believe @UdAY revealed in the comments. So your POST data can be changed to:

```
addGin() {
  axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/gins', {
    gin_name: this.gin_name,
    description: this.description,
    distillery_id: this.distillery_id.id, //this.distillery_id is being set as an object and you just need the id prop here
    abv: this.abv, snippet: this.snippet
  })
```

Comment: Also, I could be wrong, but I thought with the way your strong params are set up in your controller, your gin data needs to be nested in a gin object. Like:

{ gin: { gin_name: this.gin_name, description: this.description, distillery_id: this.distillery_id.id, abv: this.abv, snippet: this.snippet } }

Comment: Thanks Rob.  I'm just away from the laptop atm, but will take a look at this later.

Comment: I also added `    id(option) {
      return `${option.id}`
    },` which with your suggestion to add the extra `id` has actually worked!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) to get the good values?

```
 addGin() {
  let myId = options.filter(o => distillery_id.some(d => d.distillery_id === o.distillery_id));
  axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/gins', {
    gin_name: this.gin_name, 
    description: this.description, 
    distillery_id: myId, 
    abv: this.abv, 
    snippet: this.snippet
  }).then(console.log)
},
```

*I'm not sut that this works, check the code before use.*

Other way is debug the code in the line and check how you could get the id:

```
 addGin(argument1, argument2, argument3) {
  debugger; // The code will stop here, check this object to get the data and change the code!
  axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/gins', {
    gin_name: this.gin_name, 
    description: this.description, 
    distillery_id: this.distillery_id, 
    abv: this.abv, 
    snippet: this.snippet
  }).then(console.log)
},
```

I suggest to change multiselect to [vue-select](https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/docs/Basics/Values.html#multiple)
The [docs](https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/docs/Api/Props.html) seems more readable.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I'm really struggeling to get vue-select to work with nuxt.

Comment: Good to know! Try the debugger option to get the info.
Use the console to ensure your filter works :) (you have to open the chrome dev tools to make the debugger line stops when it runs).